# Measuring DC Load on Positive Ground 48vdc Telecom Power Plant

Tags: current

I wish to measure dc load on negative conductor on a 48 volt positive ground telecom power plant. Which way should arrow on clamp be pointing? Would it be safe to say the correct current load would be the direction in which current measures highest?

Comment: Your amp meter should indicate a + or - reading, giving you the same amp value no matter which way it is hooked up.

Answer (score 1):

I infer from your question you are using a clamp on current probe that can measure D.C.   I would point the "arrow" toward the positive ground.  This should  produce a negative current reading.

The magnitude shouldn't change with arrow direction, only the sign.

Answer (score 0):

If the clamp direction changes the amplitude then degauss your clamp.

I would design a shunt from the power plant and find a way to get a 10~50mV max drop calibrated.  ( like a 1" braid , flat strip or copper pipe )